# Formatting MeetingItem start date and end date

Tags: vba, outlook

`AppointmentItem.Start` returns the starttime of the event if I understand correctly and its in my case in the following format:
`"29.05.2018 08:00:00"`
How can I format it to this:
`"2018-05-29T08:00:00"`
I could replace dots with "-" but maybe there is better way to do that.
And I need to move the year to the beginning.

the same format returns AppointmentItem.End I would like to format it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim sTime As String
Dim eTime Ss String
sTime = AppointmentItem.Start
eTime = AppointmentItem.End
sTime = Format(sTime, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
eTime = Format(eTime, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")

MsgBox "Start: " & sTime & " End: " & eTime
```